# coming text up when user touch the image

Tags: android

In android app, I'd like to have an image with some text on the down part of the image and when the user touch the image i want the text to come up and to be centered in the image. Here is  a link where i found an example and  you should scroll down and then you'll be able to see the example in Recommended boards.
 https://learni.st/users/emily.dingmann.7/boards/14637-why-you-should-be-drinking-lemon-water-in-the-morning. I thought to use button with the method setOnClickListener in order to manage it. 
Is there another way to create something like that?

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that only by animating Views.You need to animate both Image(ImageView) and text(TextView) to get that kind of animation(like the one in that given link), and you need to set the onclickListner method to trigger the animation.

You can use ViewAnimation,ObjectAnimator etc to Achieve what you want.